# How to display ready RDLC report in MVC application?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, rdlc

I have a MVC application and I have a Web Service with ready RDLC reports. I want to pin this reports in my view. I have tried by `<iframe>` but content of report is invisible. I only have a navigation of report. In src of `<iframe>`I have an web address to raport.

```
 <iframe id="Reports" src="http://my web addres"
            width="95%" height="460"></iframe>
```

Where is a problem?

Comment: Can you show how you are trying to add your code to make it visible in your view?

Comment: I edited a question